# trying to display summer or winter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to display that it summer or winter bassed on lattitude and date of the month
the error is  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
import React from 'react';

const getSeason = (lat, month) =>{
    if (month > 2 && month < 9){
        lat >0 ? 'summer': 'winter';
    }else{
        lat > 0 ? 'winter': 'summer';
    }
}

const SeasonDisplay = (props)=>{
    const season = getSeason(props.lat, new Date().getMonth());
    console.log(season);
    return <div>Season Display</div>
}
export default SeasonDisplay;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the getSeason to:

```
const getSeason = (lat, month) => {
    if (month > 2 && month < 9) {
        return lat > 0 ? 'summer': 'winter';
    } else {
        return lat > 0 ? 'winter': 'summer';
    }
}
```

As I think you get that warning as you are not using the result of the ternary operator.